# Android support Toolbar not displaying custom drawable properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-toolbar

I'm trying to update my apps ActionBar into toolbar but I encountered some problem on customizing my Toolbar to display a custom drawable.

What I tried so far is to set my xml drawable into the Toolbar but it destroys the whole toolbar and moved the menu button down where I cannot properly see it:

Here's the drawable first:

**bg_actionbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_gradient" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_logo" />

</layer-list>
```

bg_gradient is just a 9patch image gradient and same with the icon_logo.

And for my toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/actionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_actionbar"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

this one pushes my menu button below and has a spacing of about 300dp on left with the icon shrinked in height.

Now I just tried to directly changed the background straight into just the png image (bg_gradient) and same thing happens. I've also tried adding an ImageView inside the Toolbar but same thing it just destroys the whole ToolBar and once again I'm lost on how I can customize this Toolbar further. Anyone has the idea? TIA.

UPDATE:

I tried adding a linear layout on the toolbar to contain the background but still it doesn't display properly on my end:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/actionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/cherry_red"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_actionbar"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here's what happened:

[image]

Additionally here's what I expected it to be:

[image]

Icon should be on center, and 9patch image as gradient since I'm having trouble on XML to have a percentage on the start mid and end colors and the navigationIcon should be on top of the gradient.

Comment: may I know what kind of toolbar you are expecting to have an sample image will be helpful.

Comment: Okay, I'll add it on the question in a minute.

Comment: Hi @Rod_Algonquin, added the sample image as requested. :)

Comment: Ahh I see what you are trying to do, the above sample wont actually work for the entire toolbar, what you need to do is to create and set the drawable in the xml such as `<item name="android:background">your drawable</item>` make sure you use `Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar` as parent now you set it in your `style` section of your toolbar

Comment: I tried your solution but it just gives me the same problem where the menu is pushed down below. I use: <style name="actionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_actionbar</item>
    </style>

and set it as style on my ToolBar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey i think this will helps because i have an app with something similar

[image: ToolBar achieve]

My xml is so:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/custom_toolbar" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="56dp" 
android:background="@drawable/actionbar_bg" >

            <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo"
            android:layout_width="140dp" android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_logo"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:clickable="true">

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

While the drawable/actionbar_bg is so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:endColor="#4093A3"
                android:angle="90" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below sample xml for your layout

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_home"
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

toolbar_home.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/actionbar_icon_bg"/>

    <ImageView android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In your Activity,

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar); //or setActionBar(toolbar)
```

To get navigation icon and stuff

```
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.btn_main_nav_selector);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // or getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

.Use

**`Gravity`** on your inner `View`

hope it helps